# Undefined symbol error when linking to a static library

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a project (project 1) that compiles to a library (`libtest.a`). It contains `test.cpp` and `test.h`, which are as follows.

`test.h` contains:

```
void test();
```

`test.cpp` contains:

```
#include "test.h"
void test() {}
```

`libtest.a` compiles with no errors or warnings.

---

I have another project (project 2) which links to `libtest.a` from project 1 that compiles to an executable binary. It contains `main.cpp`, which is as follows.

`main.cpp` contains:

```
#include "../test/test.h"

int main() {
    test();
}
```

(`../test/test.h` is the relative path from `main.cpp` in project 2 to `test.h` in project 1.)

---

When I compile project 2, I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Which is the same error I get if I remove the implementation of `test()` altogether, and if I put the definition in `test.h` instead of `test.cpp` everything compiles. This leads me to believe that project 2 is able to see `test.h` but not `test.cpp`. Why? How do I fix the problem?

Comment: What's your build command line?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: He means what command(s) are you using to compile and link your code? Can you please add it to the question? Even if you're building from an IDE (so just clicking a 'build' button) it should still be visible to you somewhere.

Comment: Anyone know where to find that information in Xcode?

Comment: Possibly silly question: did you remember to add the library itself to your XCode project?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes I did. As I said, if I put everything in `test.h` it works fine. I'm currently moving forward with my project by putting everything in header files, but I would rather use `.cpp`s for my implementation so I can hide certain things - perhaps make use of `using` statements without polluting the namespace of code that uses the library.